# Python not replacing into file

Tags: python, file, replace

I have a part of a python code which is not updating my textfile with values,please help me to fix my code

My code:

```
import re
import collections
class Group:
    def __init__(self):
        self.members = []
        self.text = []

with open('textaweq1.txt', "r+") as f:
    # so specific lines can be edited
    lines = f.readlines()

    groups = collections.defaultdict(Group)
    group_pattern = re.compile(r'^(\S+)\((.*)\)$')
    current_group = None

    for line in range(len(lines)):
        curr_line = lines[line]

        # to prevent searches on lines with no group
        if "(" in curr_line:
            curr_line = curr_line.strip()
            m = group_pattern.match(curr_line)
            if m:
                group_name, group_members = m.groups()
                groups[group_name].members += filter(lambda x: x not in groups[group_name].members, group_members.split(','))
                current_group = group_name

    already_seen = []
    for line in range(len(lines)):
        curr_line = lines[line]

        for key in groups.keys():
            if key in curr_line.strip():
                if key in already_seen:
                    lines[line] = ""
                else:
                    already_seen.append(key)
                    open_par = curr_line.index("(")
                    close_par = curr_line.index(")")

                    member_str = ",".join(groups[key].members)

                    lines[line] = curr_line[:open_par+1] + member_str + curr_line[close_par:]
                    print groups[key].members
                    if 'skoda' in groups[key].members:
                        print 'yes'
                    listnames=[]
                    if 'skoda' in groups[key].members:
                        listnames.append('animal')
                    if 'dog' in groups[key].members:
                        listnames.append('animal')
                    allText = f.read()
                    allText = allText.replace('pets()', 'pets(' + ', '.join(listnames) + ')') # or use re python
                    f.write(allText)


    # clear the file and reset the file cursor
    f.truncate()
    f.seek(0)

    for line in lines:
        f.write(line)
```

Error:

```
  File "C:\Python27\awegedir.py", line 54, in <module>
    f.write(allText)
IOError: [Errno 0] Error
```

But my code is not writing and replcing pets() its remaining same as text file.
Please mention my mistake over the code and fix them!

Comment: How do you know it's not "writing and replacing `pets()`"? Did you look into the file or do you get an error.

Comment: i get error as    IOError: [Errno 0] Error

Comment: i have posted the running code!

Comment: Do you have permission to write to that file.

Comment: yes i have permission to write to file

Answer (score 0):

What you do is this:

1. Read the read into a list of lines
2. Read some more from the same file handle. This second read won't do anything since you already have read everything - it will return an empty string. So `allText` will be empty.
3. Since `allText` is empty, `.replace()` has no effect at all
4. Then you append this empty string to the end of the file -> no effect again
5. Then you truncate the file (deleting any change which `f.write(allText)` could have done)
6. Then you write the original lines back into the file (this would also overwrite any change done by `f.write()`).

All in all, your approach looks very complex to me. Try to split it in several steps:

1. Load the file into a data structure (maybe a list of lines)
2. First collect all those keys, etc.
3. Then replace the pattern in each line
4. Close the file (= leave the `with open(..., 'r')` block)
5. Open the file again for writing and write all the lines into the file

Comment: could you please fix my entire code/specific area of my code?

Comment: How coul i fix this issue then/.

Comment: I'm really wondering what `Errno 0` is supposed to be - errno 0 means "no error" but Python still throws an `IOError`. From the path, this looks like Windows. Does it work when you move your code to a different folder than `C:\Python27\`? Windows usually doesn't like it when you write into the install folder of software.